# How do I get the functionality of printf to an EditControl in MFC

Tags: c++, mfc, printf, editcontrol

I am developing an MFC application. The UI will contain a Listbox with multiple options.
 Each selection in the list box has a respective function to be executed. I have written event handlers for doubleclick of the listbox selections.

There are few scenarios in each function where in I may have to display a few messages and a few values (just like how we do with printf).

I would like to know how to achieve this with EditControl. I want these messages to appear in the EditControl.

Comment: Pass to the code doing the work a pointer to the dialog, so that you can call an appropriate public dialog function to populate the controls. Or add more information if the design is more complex ???

Answer (score 1):

I might have missed the point here but can you not use a CString and the Format function to setup the string before displaying it?

Comment: I did try that but dint help me much

Comment: Could you be a bit more specific?  What exactly did it not do that you need?  It does everything that printf does.

Comment: I did use this, but In output i got few junk values...                a쳌쳌쳌쳌쳌쳌쳌쳌쳌쳌쳌쳌쳌쳌쳌쳌쳌 : identifier  instead of a: identifier                                                             Here a is a char array

Comment: Got the answer.. The issue was the ANSI-Unicode conversions.I had declared an array in ANSI and was using it with str.Format so changing the declared array to Unicode helped me in solving the problem

Comment: Ah, yes that would do it.  Good spot.